# Filepath on Mac for local Parquet files in Spark program in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I have a small Spark program in Java, that reads parquet files from a local directory on a Mac.
I have been trying to do this multiple ways, but nothing seems to be working.

```
Dataset<Row> dsuomcategoryconvfactor = spark.read().parquet(path + "file:///usr/local⁩/ParquetData/data1.parquet");
```

I think I am giving the path wrong for Spark to identify it, and it's throwing the below error.

```
20/01/06 10:58:29 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4/libexec/work/driver-20200106105812-0006/spark-warehouse'.
20/01/06 10:58:29 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/usr/local⁩/ParquetData/data1.parquet;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:628)
```

This works fine when run from an IDE, but when I submit the job from shell using spark-submit, this error is being thrown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried path like /usr/local⁩/ParquetData/data1.parquet and also does the parquet file exists at this path?

Comment: Yes, the file does exist in that path.

Comment: Do you need the `path + ` part?  It looks like you may be concatenating together two paths?

Comment: It's not actually needed. ```path``` is just an empty string in this case though.